# cron, trouble with starting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have problem with starting cron on my VM machine. When i force it to start I've got an error: Can't find "var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket". File is missing. in rcconf cron is on

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the D-Bus/messagebus service first.

Comment: yea, the package, dbus if you are using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is useful:

http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell#line-135

http://live.gnome.org/JhbuildIssues/dbus#line867